# TI nSpire CX CAS impossible answer

Tags: calculator

My input to my TI nSpire CX CAS was:

$solve(\frac{r\cdot (p+q)}{p\cdot q}<5$ and $p>0$ and $r>0$ and $q>0,p)$

The first answer it gave was

$0<p<\frac{-q\cdot r}{r-5\cdot q}$ and $r-5\cdot q>0$ and $r>0$ and $q>0$

which is impossible.

If $r$,$q$, and $r-5\cdot q$ are all non-zero and positive then $\frac{-q\cdot r}{r-5\cdot q}$ is negative and
p cannot be non-zero and both negative and positive at the same time.

The second answer after the 'or' it gave was also impossible. It gave

$0<p<min(0,\frac{-q\cdot r}{r-5\cdot q})$ and $0<r<5\cdot q$ and $q>0$

Why does it give this result? Is there a bug in the calculator?

Comment: Is this calculator supposed to be able to solve a system of inequalities?

Comment: If I only try to solve the first inequality for $p$, it gives the same result, along with canvassing all the other solutions with $p$, $q$, and $r$ taking positive or negative values.  I included the positive constraints on $p$,$q$, and $r$ to cut down on the number of solutions the calculator gave.